# R - Why does 'regexpr()' not find string if a pattern start with it?

Tags: r, regex

Why does `regexpr()` not find the word `foo` in this case:

```
foobar <- data.frame(one=c("foo bar", "foo"))
regexpr("foo",foobar[,1])>1

[1] FALSE FALSE
```

But does in this case:

```
foobar <- data.frame(one=c("bar foo", " foo"))
regexpr("foo",foobar[,1])>1  

[1] TRUE TRUE
```

It would be nice if you could give an explaination besids from a solution.
Thanks allot

Comment: You can check the output of `regexpr(....)` without the logical.  In the first case, it starts from position 1, so both values are 1, and your logical comparison is `>1`

Comment: `regexpr` find the pattern in both cases : try `regexpr("foo",foobar[,1])`. Read the help and you will find that `regexpr` returns vectors with the positions of the match, the length of the match and TRUE or FALSE. In the second case it is one so it returns FALSE

Comment: You are being confused by the additional attributes printed probably. Just check `c(regexpr("foo",foobar[,1])) ` in both cases. And then read the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because we are getting the position index with `regexpr`

```
 regexpr("foo",foobar[,1])
 #[1] 1 1
 #attr(,"match.length")
 #[1] 3 3
 #attr(,"useBytes")
 #[1] TRUE
```

and for the second one, it is

```
 #[1] 5 2
```